# Assigning a value to an instance of a class in C# implicitly

Tags: c#, class, instantiation

I have a custom class, `ComplexNumber`, which is as you may expect a way to represent complex numbers:

```
class ComplexNumber
{
    double realPart;
    double imaginaryPart;

    public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        realPart = real;
        imaginaryPart = imaginary;
    }
}
```

The context of this question is that if you want to set default C# classes such as a double or a float to a certain value which is an integer, you can write

```
float f = 2;
```

I want to be able to write something similar like

```
ComplexNumber c = 2;
```

which will create a new variable of the `ComplexNumber` class with its `realPart` set to `2` and its `imaginaryPart` set to `0`. To write `ComplexNumber c = new ComplexNumber(2, 0)` is much more tedious, and I am wondering if there is a way to create these instances of a custom class more implicitly like how the default C# classes behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [implicit (or expicit)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) operator to your class like so:

```
public static implicit operator ComplexNumber(int i) => new ComplexNumber(i, 0);
```

That will allow you do what you want.

As you used `2` as a literal, that will be an `int` in C#, this then relies on the fact that `int` is implicitly convertable to `double` in the contructor call to `ComplexNumber`.

Comment: I would definitely make the implicit operator accept `double` as an input instead of `int`. If it accepts `int` then the implicit operator won't work if you already have a `double` which you want to implicitly convert to `ComplexNumber`. On the other hand, if it accepts `double`, it will work with both `double` and `int`